# Gradle : Android Project compile with other project

Tags: java, android

I am new to Gradle project.

First, I create a Android project `TryAd` in Android Studio. Since I have to import another other project as a library, my project' structure is:

```
--TryAd
   --app
      --build.gradle
   --library
      --build.gradle 
   settings.gradle
```

in the `settings.gradle`,

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

And in `build.gradle` of `app`,

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(":library")

}
```

What makes confused is that, why classes in  `.jar` files in `library/libs` path cannot  be used in the `app` project ?

Should I copy those .`jar` files from `libraray/libs` to `app/libs`

PS: `build.gradle` in `library` project,

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {}
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildTypes {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What is your build.gradle of your library project?

Comment: in library project, I have declared : apply plugin: 'android-library'

Comment: I'm talking about the whole file. Dependencies too.

Comment: in library project, dependency is : dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}

Comment: I think the problem is because you're not compiling the libs too. Try adding `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` too